# Finding the reason for pods being killed by Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I created a Minikube instance in my local machine on top of Virtual Box. I have a couple of replication controllers with resource limits specified for both of them. First I created one instance per each replication controller A and B. Then I increased the replication count of rc B to 6. Once it is being scaling up, I can see that the Pod created by rc A is killed by Kubernetes. Only log I can see in kubeclt logs is

```
/opt/app-server/bin/app-server.sh: line 159:    28 Killed                  $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -server $JVM_OPTS $XDEBUG $SERVER_OPTS -Djava.endorsed.dirs=$SERVER_ENDORSED -classpath $SERVER_CLASSPATH org.adroitlogic.appserver.AppServer
```

I have no clue what caused for the eviction of this pod. I'm guessing this is related to the resource allocation of pods and limited resources on VM. But I need to confirm that. Where can I find the logs related to the reason of eviction of this pod? I searched in journalctl -u localkube

```
Jan 09 11:00:55 minikube localkube[3421]: I0109 11:00:55.136114    3421 docker_manager.go:2524] checking backoff for container "ipsweb" in pod "ipsweb-m3234"
Jan 09 11:00:55 minikube localkube[3421]: I0109 11:00:55.136525    3421 docker_manager.go:2538] Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=ipsweb pod=ipsweb-m3234_default(e6961157-d650-11e6-8bee-080027bc9720)
Jan 09 11:00:55 minikube localkube[3421]: E0109 11:00:55.136571    3421 pod_workers.go:184] Error syncing pod e6961157-d650-11e6-8bee-080027bc9720, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "ipsweb" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=ipsweb pod=ipsweb-m3234_default(e6961157-d650-11e6-8bee-080027bc9720)"
```

kubectl describe pod gives following events

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath       Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------       --------    ------      -------
  1h        1h      1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal      Started     Started container with docker id 2ca5ccaa11a1
  1h        1h      1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal      Created     Created container with docker id 2ca5ccaa11a1; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
  1h        1h      1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal      Started     Started container with docker id 86d4bdfa014e
  1h        1h      1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal      Created     Created container with docker id 86d4bdfa014e; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
  50m       50m     1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal      Started     Started container with docker id a570e4f59e96
  50m       50m     1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal      Created     Created container with docker id a570e4f59e96; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
  1h        49m     2   {kubelet minikube}              Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "ipsweb" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=ipsweb pod=ipsweb-m3234_default(e6961157-d650-11e6-8bee-080027bc9720)"

  49m   49m 1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal  Started     Started container with docker id b91cc20a8bb3
  49m   49m 1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal  Created     Created container with docker id b91cc20a8bb3; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
  1h    48m 4   {kubelet minikube}              Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "ipsweb" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=ipsweb pod=ipsweb-m3234_default(e6961157-d650-11e6-8bee-080027bc9720)"

  48m   48m 1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal  Started     Started container with docker id cf24faa31718
  48m   48m 1   {kubelet minikube}  spec.containers{ipsweb} Normal  Created     Created container with docker id cf24faa31718; Security:[seccomp=unconfined]
  1h    46m 7   {kubelet minikube}              Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "ipsweb" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=ipsweb pod=ipsweb-m3234_default(e6961157-d650-11e6-8bee-080027bc9720)"
```

But non of the above gives me a hint about the cause and why this is happening. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know what is the correct way to do it but here is what I do when k8s cannot give me enough information.

The easiest thing to do is to see `docker logs` of that pod. I see that certain pod is failing again and again. So I would goto minikube machine and run

`docker ps -a | grep 'some_identifiable_name'`

this is where I get the container id. Once I have that I get logs of that pod.

`docker logs <id_found_above>`

This should be done so quickly because k8s might garbage collect the container before you can even perform all of above steps.

Answer (score 0):

To get logs of each pod in simple way, run following command,

`$ minikube dashboard`

then `kubernetes` dashboard will open up in your browser. then goto `Pods`, under containers tab, there will be option `View logs` from where you can actually see what's going on inside container or why it's failing